# Do you pay comission twice when your app works both in Android and iOS?

Tags: google-play-store, ios

If my app user bought subscription in Android store and paid commission - do I have to pay the commission again at the iOS store ?

Comment: There is no app that works on both platforms. Each platform need an individual app compiled for the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Store and Apple Store are platforms managed by two different entities. What you bought on one store is not reflected/extended to the other. So, you will have to buy/pay for the same app on both stores.

If you can access your app with the same account, for example a game, what you bought might be reflected thanks to using the same account on both platforms.